# Color Function in Python

Tags: python, function, colors, hex

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) I learned how to color Python. I figured out all the color codes, don't worry. 
Anyway, the answer that worked for me was the ctypes one by orip. It's a bit tiresome to have to have to type `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, AQUA)` every time I want to color text. Is there a way to convert it into a function? I'm not sure how to send variables through functions, and not sure how to implement them, even if I did.
Thanks in advance! -ghostmancer

All that matters for me is that it works for me - I'm not planning to give my script away.
My colors:

```
BLACK    = 0x0000
BLUE    = 0x0001
GREEN    = 0x0002
RED    = 0x0004
PURPLE    = 0x0005
YELLOW    = 0x0006
WHITE    = 0x0007
GRAY    = 0x0008
GREY    = 0x0008
AQUA    = 0x0009 #Very Blue
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 0x3? And 0xb for the light version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ummm... if i understand right ...

```
def a_func(handle,color):
   ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, color)

a_func(handle,AQUA)
```

or even better

```
colorFunc = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute
colorFunc(handle,AQUA)
```

Comment: Or even better-er: `from ctypes.windll.kernel32 import SetConsoleTextAttribute as set_color`. If anyone actually cares for portability outside of Windows, then option #1 is best, as it provides an abstraction that you can proliferate in your program and only need to change one location inside the abstracted function later (e.g. adding GNU+Linux support).

Answer (score 2):

no need to create a new function with `def` or `lambda`, just assign the function with a long name to a shorter name, e.g:

```
textcolor = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute
textcolor(handle, color)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
def textcolor(handle, color):
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, color)
```

which you call like so:

```
textcolor(handle, AQUA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
f=lambda handle,color:ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, color)
```

and, call `f(<Actual handle object>, <color>)` wherever you want.
e.g. `f(handle, AQUA)` would be the required call

Answer (score 0):

Because I see the variable 'handle' everywhere without being defined and for anyone who wonders, here is a way to get it, as far as stdout is concerned, so that we can used it with `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, color)`:

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
```